# Number of spark jobs and stages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark job, which reads two csv files with header=True (no infer_schema). Then joins these 2 dataframes, performs group by and finally write as csv.

**Steps:**

- Read csv file1 with header=True (no infer_schema)
- Read csv file2 with header=True (no infer_schema)
- Join file1 and file2 (not a broadcast)
- Perform group by
- write grouped data as results in csv format

**Question**: How many job and stages are created?

- My understanding is 3 jobs will be created - two for reading and one for writing.
- 2 stages will be created - one for join and another for group by

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

The number of jobs corresponds to the number of actions

- No of jobs = No of actions

The number of stages aligns with the count of wide transformations.

- No of Stage = No of wide transformation

In your scenario, you will have three jobs reflecting the three actions, and two stages due to the inclusion of wide transformations, such as group by and join operations